# Transferring specific data from one db to another locally

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, synchronization

Ok here is the situation.  We have a client application that contains a local sql database.  At any given time, they could be working in the field and may have no internet connection at all.  This means they cannot sync back to the server or to anything else.  Client A needs to export specific pipe information that will include data from several tables and will have to hand off this information to Client B that will continue to work on this.  Client A will then need to put this information on a file and give to Client B.  Client B will then need to import this pipe information into his local database.
I'm brainstorming for ideas of what could be the best solution to accomplish this?

So far querying the specific pipe information, writing to a file in xml and then importing the xml and writing to the database could be an option.
Or just querying the information and writing sql scripts that can be executed on client Bs machine.
We just can't export the entire databases information from one computer to another. It has to be only specific information the user wants to export.

Comment: Look into "replication".

Comment: The `DataTable` and `DataSet` classes both have `WriteXml` and `ReadXml` methods, so I'd probably go with that.

Comment: Generally, questions like this are off topic because they are too broad and based on opinion. In my opinion, as **jmcilhinney** pointed, having DataSet filled with necessary and export/import data is good enough. You can store it in XML file easily and update Server when connection is available. All you have to do is to separate logic of working with your data, and synchronizing. Always work against local and synch when connection exists.